# How to use kapt in a kotlin library module

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kapt

I've added `kotlin("kapt")` to the `plugins` block in the build.gradle.kts file for my library module.

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id ("kotlin")
    kotlin("kapt")
}
```

Now gradle sync results in the error:

> only id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

how can I make use of kapt in my library module?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Silly me.  A copy-paste mix-up caused the .kts extension to be removed from my file.  Restoring the filename extension resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle Kotlin DSL use:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("kapt") version "version" // e.g. "1.7.21"
}
```

As for Groovy:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "version" // e.g. "1.7.21"
}
```

I used it and it worked!